# Is it possible to get sunrise/sunset in android WITHOUT location or the light sensor?

Tags: java, android

I want to know aproximately when is light and when is dark **WITHOUT** relying on gps, location or the light sensor of the device. Is it possible?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: There are probably APIs around with these data.

Answer (score 4):

well, you must know at least coarse location of user, sunrise/sunset time is different in center of north pole and equator, isn't it?

on Android you can get approximate location with

`Locale.getDefault().getCountry()`

or

`Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()`

[some wiki explanation how to calculate sunrise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_equation)

[some Github project with Android widget](https://github.com/forrestguice/SuntimesWidget), you can inspect sources